# using case_when along with dplyr::filter() to condense several nested ifelse statements

Tags: r, dplyr, logic

I am writing a function that takes 4 inputs and formats a data frame according to the values of the inputs using dplyr. Note that each input can have 2 values, "None" or "X". I want to write a function that will only filter the fields that have value "X" and will calculate a summary statistic after filtering and grouping on the fields that have value "X". I have written a very cumbersome version of this which involves lots of nested if else loops in order to filter for each of the 16 possible combinations of values for the 4 input variables. I would like to be able to condense this code and I believe that I should be able to do it using case_when, filter and group_by in dplyr, but I am struggling to understand how to do so.

```
x1 <- c(rep(0:1, each = 8))
x2 <- c(rep(0:1, 8))
x3 <- c(rep(0:1, each = 4, times = 2))
x4 <- c(rep(0:1, each = 2, times = 4))
y <- c(seq(1:16))

df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,y)
```

So my df is:

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4  y
1   0  0  0  0  1
2   0  1  0  0  2
3   0  0  0  1  3
4   0  1  0  1  4
5   0  0  1  0  5
6   0  1  1  0  6
7   0  0  1  1  7
8   0  1  1  1  8
9   1  0  0  0  9
10  1  1  0  0 10
11  1  0  0  1 11
12  1  1  0  1 12
13  1  0  1  0 13
14  1  1  1  0 14
15  1  0  1  1 15
16  1  1  1  1 16
```

My function is:

```
    exampleFX <- function(z1, z2, z3, z4) {
      df <- dplyr::filter(dplyr::case_when(
                      z1 != 0 ~ x1 == z1,
                      z2 != 0 ~ x2 == z2,
                      z3 != 0 ~ x3 == z3,
                      z4 != 0 ~ x4 == z4
      ))
      return(df$y)
    }
```

and when I test it,

```
exampleFX(0,1,0,1)
```

, I expect to get df$y = 4. However, I get the following error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Comment: `case_when` is going to only filter based on _one_ of those four rows in your `case_when`, is that what you mean? That is, in your example of `exampleFX(0,1,0,1)`, once `case_when` sees `z2 != 0`, nothing after that is considered. Are you hoping instead to be an "AND" operation on all four variables?

Comment: I don't understand your expectation. If by `z1 != 0` you mean to say that you don't want to test if `x1 == z1` when `z1` is zero, then when `z1 = 0`, I would expect `x1` permitted values to be _anything_.  There is no logic I can see (atm) where you conditionally filter (`0` means "do not filter on this variable), args of `0,1,0,1`, and get only one row in return.

Comment: Last issue: `filter` needs its first argument to be a `data.frame`, you're ignoring that. I suggest you write your function as `exampleFX <- function(X, z1, z2, z3, z4) dplyr::filter(X, ...)`, and then either call it as `exampleFX(df, 0, 1, 0, 1)` or `df %>% exampleDF(0, 1, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. I get the sense that there is a much more elegant way of doing what you're attempting to do, but it's hard to say without seeing more code and/or data. For example, what are z1-z4? Can you include your "very cumbersome" version?

Comment: Did you resolve your question? We identified some issues/options and you commented a way that your sample data is not representative. If your question is still unresolved, please update your data to better reflect what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want your function to do. From your example it seems like you simply want to check whether all four columns match and return the value of y when there is a match. In which case something like this should work:

```
exampleFX <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
  match_row <- df[df$x1 == x1 & df$x2 == x2 & df$x3 == x3 & df$x4 == x4, ]
  return(match_row$y)
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you mean.

Comment: I understand the confusion. The reality of the data that I have is that the 0 value doesn't actually exist in my dataframe and instead represents a higher level of aggregation. My bad for not providing a great example. I will try to come up with a better dummy dataset to make my question make more sense. Thanks!